# $stateChangeStart with params variable on event angularJS

Tags: angularjs

i'm passing a parms object OBJ from a ui-serf detail to a stateDetail that go to another state createStep1, i setted in params of the two state the parms OBJ and in my run function in app.js i put the params again with toPrams as follows:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState,toParams) {
if(toState.name =='stateDetail'){
        console.log("toParams "+toParams);
            $state.go('createStep1',{OBJ:toParams});
             event.preventDefault();

        }

}}
```

In the controller of createStep1 the param OBJ came undefined but in the on method it is in toParams.

Here is the states:

```
state('stateDetail', {
  url: '/stateDetail',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'stateDetail.html',
      controller: 'DetailsController'

    },
  },
  params: {
      OBJ: null

  }
})


state('createStep1', {
  url: '/createStep1',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'createStep1.html',
      controller: 'createStep1Controller'

    },
  },
  params: {
      OBJ: null

  }
})
```

in html page:

```
<a  ui-sref="stateDetail({OBJ: obj})"   >{{obj.id}}</a>
```

Any idea how can i fix this issue?

Comment: got it it must    $state.go('createStep1',{OBJ:toParams.OBJ});

Answer (score 0):

it must to be    $state.go('createStep1',{OBJ:toParams.OBJ});